# NewRelic Availability Monitoring of Third Party Service

Tags: monitoring, ping, system-monitoring, availability

**Background**

NewRelic offers availability monitoring whereby you can specify a ping URL for an application and have NewRelic send HTTP GET requests to that URL and GREP the response for selected text, or simply check that the HTTP return status shows the URL is up (including the advanced ability to treat redirects as success or error).

We use a third party service, which I've been able to use the availability monitor on to ensure it's working correctly; however to do this I had to set the ping URL against one of our existing applications.

**Question**

Is there a way to create a new application without using the Server or .Net (or related) components, but simply as an entry in NewRelic on which we could then set a Ping URL?

Comment: Why not use Pingdom.com or something?

Comment: Good shout @ceejayoz.  The main reason is simplicity - we're trying to limit our toolset so that we don't have to map out what service to use for each piece of functionality (my company's at the Enterprise end, so we have a huge amount of systems, servers and services to monitor, so it can get quite complex).  NewRelic's looked the most promising overall service so far, so we're trialling that.